# Variable Names and String data in .mat file Corrupted

Tags: string, matlab, corruption

We have been using a COM DLL written against the MATLAB API (supported by MATLAB Compiler Runtimes 7.11 and 7.15) from with VB6 for several years now to write .mat files and save a figure to a .png file. All of a sudden, the variable names and string data contained in the .mat file are mangled at their ends with extraneous characters. Seems isolated to my computer. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

[Matlab Variable Editor Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLm7D.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found by a bit of trial and error and code comparison.

The previously working declaration in c# was:

```
internal static extern IntPtr mxCreateString_proxy([In]Char[] CharStr);
```

The declaration had to be changed to the following (to avoid mangling the string data):

```
 internal static extern IntPtr mxCreateString_proxy(String CharStr);
```

This simple soultion was arrived at after many failed attempts to Marshal in various ways the Char array.

As background, to my knowledge Matlab does NOT publish an API to their runtimes. How the previous developer got the signatures I do not know.

That said, in a separate declaration to another runtime function mclInitializeApplication_proxy I saw that the Options argument to it (a string) was being passed as String.

```
 internal static extern Boolean mclInitializeApplication_proxy(String options, Int32 count);
```

So, I decided if that function declaration used String to pass string data then I might as well try passing the string data I needed to send as String instead Char[]. Voila' it worked.

I just thought I'd post the soultion in case anybody else has a similar problem.